# "extendBodyBehindAppBar: true," Margins are created

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Problem
When I type "extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,"
I get a blank space.

I want to remove this.
Do you know anyone？？？

extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,

[image]

extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,

[image]

code

```
 body: Container(

      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('images/top_background.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TopCarousel(),
            _topPageStream.when(
                data: (data) => ListView(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: data.docs
```

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by blank space? I don't understand what the problem is. Could you please point to where the unexpected behavior is exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's the bottom of the carousel in the first image.

Comment: Ohh I see the problem now. I don't know why that would happen even after reading your code as `extendBodyBehindAppBar` doesn't change the children. Try using the dart dev tools and seeing what is creating that space. I don't have your full code so I cannot do that myself.